# How to add dynamic data in an HTML document via a Power Automate flow?

Tags: html, onedrive, powerapps, power-automate

I'm working on a flow to take data from a SharePoint list, and add it to a specific point in HTML. I am just saving the outputted HTML file to my OneDrive whilst testing.

I have found that when pasting my HTML code into a compose block, then outputting this, it works fine and I'm left with a normal looking HTML page when opened in a browser.

However, as soon as I add dynamic data in place of certain HTML elements it all seems to go wrong.

Firstly, the outputted HTML file now contains '/n' in place of every line break. I have also noticed that the outputted HTML code has now been changed to an array.

I've attached screenshots of my flow below.

**Get Items:**
[image]

**Compose:**
[image]

**Create File:**
[image]

**Create File Peek Code:**
[image]

**Compose Output:**
[image]

**Create Output:**
[image]

**Create Output Raw:**
[image]

**Outputted HTML File:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you processing the output from that Compose action?

What you are doing is correct and it would not matter if you are using a single or multiple lines of text.

It seems to me that you are using the output of the compose somewhere else or maybe the file content box in the OneDrive action has an expression?

Please check the following:

1. The output of the compose should look normally
2. Make sure your OneDrive's action parameters look like this when you "Peek code" (Click on the action's ellipses). If it looks different, you'll have to track the variable/output you are using or review the expression.

   [image: OneDrive Peek Code]

I have replicated what you are doing and it is working fine, see attached images.

**Edit mode:**

[image: Compose HTML and save to OneDrive]

**Run:**

Compose action

[image: Compose action]

OneDrive action

[image: OneDrive action]

**Created File in OneDrive:**

[image: Created File]

EDIT: Update response to use the result from SharePoint in two different ways.

1. Use the OneDrive action inside the 'Apply to each' if there is only 1 result, it will run once anyway.
2. You can omit the 'Apply to each' action using the expression box to set the values in the Compose, this is the syntax you can use.

   outputs('Get_items')?['body']?['value']?[***rowIndex***]?['***ColumnName***']

In case there are several rows in the result, you'll have to validate which is the one you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I've checked the points you've listed and, everything looks the same. I should have said, I am using the filter function in the sharepoint 'get items' step. I've removed the filter but I still get the same result. I have just tried to make the flow again, but now it won't allow me to select the output from compose for the create file function, it just allows me to select the 'Current Item' from Apply to Each. I have written the file type as an expression (outputs('Compose') but it still gives the same issue. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, sometimes it does that where it does not show the outputs and you have to enter the value as an expression. Can you post some screenshots of how the output is setup in the OneDrive action, and  another one from the output of the compose? similar to the ones I added? This is to see if there is anything else we might be missing. If there is no confidential process/data, a full image of the process will be really helpful to debug. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for replying again! I've edited my original post above to include the details you've asked for. I hope this helps. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful! I see that the OneDrive action is outside of the 'Apply to each'. since the 'Apply to each' can iterate on different results, when you reference the outputs outside of it, it is concatenating every possible iteration, this is why you get the array result. There are two recommendation. If the filter will give just 1 result.

1.- Take the OneDrive action inside the 'Apply to each'
2.- Use expressions to remove the 'Apply to each' section

Comment: I have edited my answer with the 2 options and a sample of the expression you can use. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Excellent, option 1 worked! I put the create file inside the Apply to each block, set the file content as the output from the compose block, and it worked first time! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!